# Impossible use of mmap with zipfile open

Tags: binary, zip, mmap

I can't find a way to use mmap with a file object openned with Zipfile from a zip archive. It seems that the issue is related to the 'r' mode of the open method of ZipFile.
Indeed, if i directly work with the uncompressed source file with open and 'rb' i can use mmap with no issue but with the zipped version openned with ZipFile i get the error: "UnsupportedOperation: fileno"

My code:

`with zipfile.ZipFile(r"path\test.zip","r") as zip:`

```
with zip.open(r"myfile", 'r', 0) as file:    
    s = mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
```

=> error: UnsupportedOperation: fileno

I am looking for a way to search many zip files (large text files zipped) efficiently. Mmap is very good with my text files but seems to not work with the zipped versions of my files.

TY

Comment: How do you plan to use the mmap result? Do you actually use it as memory, or just as a magic make-it-faster thing that you then read from as normal?

Comment: i just use the mmap result to search a regex pattern. The only reason to use mmap is the speed of the search due to the size of my text files (around 8 to 12Go per file). I would like to avoid unzipping each file (60 files in total) before doing the search...Thanks a lot